# Getting Users name from federated login

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid

I am using the federated login on Google App Engine for letting users log in.

Using the information about the federated login;
 https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid

and the reference on the user object;
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/

I can get users to log in and authenticate them. I can get their email addresses and nickname.

The only problem is that I don't know how to get their actual names.
When I log in using this service the user name is provided, and stackoverflow gets the users name from the openid login (at least using Google and Yahoo).

Answer (score 0):

It should depend on the OpenID provider, and what they return as the OpenID identifier. What OpenID provider are you using?

[In regards to User.nickname():](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass)

> Returns the "nickname" of the user, a displayable name. **For Google Accounts users, the nickname is either the "name"** portion of the user's email address if the address is in the same domain as the application, or the user's full email address otherwise. **For OpenID users, the nickname is the OpenID identifier**.

So by default, it's just whatever their OpenID identifier is. Whether or not you can retrieve the username they have with their OpenID provider (if it's not the identifier) likely just depends on the provider.